Mapping Spacetime (4D Scalar Manifold) to a 3D Vector Field with Time as a Vector
I'm working on a 3Dproject where I need to develop an API to map a 4-dimensional scalar manifold (spacetime) to a 3-dimensional vector field. However, instead of treating time as a scalar, I'm representing time as a vector. The aim is to translate the coordinates from spacetime into a vector field description, where time contributes to the vectorial properties of the system.
Problem Outline:
Spacetime Setup:
    4D manifold consisting of three spatial coordinates (x, y, z) and one temporal coordinate (t).
    I want to avoid the traditional spacetime curvature model and flatten space, treating it as flat Euclidean space.

Desired Mapping:
    I need to map these 4D coordinates into a 3D vector field F(x,y,z)F(x,y,z), where time tt becomes a vector component rather than just a scalar.
    I’m trying to capture how time, represented as a vector, can influence or be part of the vector field’s behavior in this mapping.

Questions:
How would you suggest formulating the mapping from 4D spacetime (x, y, z, t) into a 3D vector field with time treated as a vector component? What mathematical constructs or tools should I use to define this transformation?

What considerations should I keep in mind when developing an API to implement this translation in a computational system?

Are there any existing models or approaches (from differential geometry, field theory, or another branch) that would be helpful for this kind of mapping?

Additional Context:
I’m primarily interested in a mathematical foundation for this mapping and how I can use this to program an API that takes spacetime coordinates as input and returns the corresponding 3D vector field representation.
I’m open to suggestions on how to best approach this, including any references to literature or examples of similar transformations.

Thank you for your help!

Hard to follow. 4D space time has coordinates $(t,x,y,z),.$ In DG a vector field is a little more than a bunch of numbers (three in your case? perhaps (x,y,z)?) which depend on something else (time in your case?). Anyway: a vector field has to obey certain transformation rules that are quite different from those for $(t,x,y,z)$ in order to be coordinate independent.

In essence, I am doing some 3D visualizations using a game engine, and would like to mathematically move the curvature of spacetime, to only time curvature, by allowing the pace of timeflow to be variable,  Looking for an alternate way to visualize spacetie curvature. in flat space.

I am sure that many physicists would love to have such a video game :) Jokes aside: There is not only the problem that spacetime is four dimensional. We can visualize  a two-dimensional surface in $\mathbb R^3$ but what we see has for our eyes  a Riemannian metric and not a pseudo-Riemannian metric where "lengths" can be negative.  I googled a bit and all results always used the dodgy analogue of a curved Riemannian surface. Good luck.

*squared "lengths" to be precise.

Kurt, Thank-you for your feedback
That is precisely the puzzle. In order to model the geometry the way i hoped. I need flat space. I was planning to accept negative time and a few additional quirks.
I was hoping a kind Math brain could point me in the best direction. I'm just aan inspired CAD guy. I thought if i characterized ADM formalism in a peculiar way i could move all curvature to a time vector, just "smash" all distortion, including letting the speed of light become the speed of time. into a vector field
